# Using references for readability in C++

Tags: c++

I have picked up a habit of using references for readability in C++.

I assume that the compiler should be capable of optimizing away any inefficiency this causes, but I was curious if any of you know for sure.

I do things like this:

```cpp
auto &device = system_context_.GetDeviceHandle();

device.init();
```

Instead of:

```cpp
system_context_.GetDeviceHandle().init();
```

Objectively, is there any efficiency loss in doing this?

Comment: Compared to what? (How else could you do it?)

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to compile the code and check the assembly.  That said, if a compiler did not do this optimization i would be very surprised and uninstalling it.

Comment: 1. Not enough context. 2. looks like micro-optimization. 3. Note there is "as-if rule". 4. If `system_context_.GetDeviceHandle()` returns reference to object which lifetime is not well defined and in not longer then use of `device` can lead to UB.

Comment: There is a semantic difference not just a readability one. References must refer to valid objects (they must not have gone out of scope), while pointers can be nullptr. So in your example GetDeviceHandle should throw if it cannot assign a valid value to your reference. So in code I make a clear distinction between the two and it is not based on "readability"

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, I edited the question to make it less subjective, and I added the "instead" clause.

Comment: @PepijnKramer How would `GetDeviceHandle` return an invalid object? Which type would it return? Can there be any example, which would be valid with directly calling `init` on the returned value compared to calling it stored in the `device` reference variable under the condition `device.init()` is just the next line (so no other function calls in between)?

Comment: @WilderField You are using rules for temporary lifetimes https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime (Temporary object lifetime) and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization (Temporary materialization) and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization (Reference initialization)

Comment: @Sebastian I was more talking in general that there is a semantic difference between pointers/references. But I see now that this was not really an answer to your question. If the function would not be able to return a valid reference it should throw anyway. 
And if you really want to know if your solution has any performance impact you can try it out on https://godbolt.org/ (it will show you generated assembly).  I don't expect it to make any runtime difference.

Comment: Also compilers are very good nowadays, if you're interested [What has my compiler done for me lately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4)

Comment: @PepijnKramer The question as by WilderField, only the following comment was by me. But never mind. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments I wrote a toy example, and used godbolt to check for a difference in assembly.

With compiler optimizations enabled there is no difference in the assembly, and thus there can be no performance delta.

Without compiler optimizations, using the reference does incur some extra move instructions.

https://godbolt.org/z/3K15r4cz3

Without optimizations:
Left side is using local reference, right side is with long line of code.
[image: diff]

Comment: You should turn optimizations on for a comparison under production circumstances.

Comment: Big mistake checking if the compiler optimizes away the reference, without turning on optimization. Compiling with -O2 gives the exact same result for your code, with or without reference.

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake @Sebastian and cptFracassa